# Getting the generic Type of a generic object when only given its superclass

Tags: c#, oop, generics, types

Suppose that we have

```
abstract class Parent
{

}

class Child<T> : Parent where T : CollectionBase
{

}
```

And some list of `Parent`:

```
List<Parent> list = new List<Parent>();
```

I want to be able to map Child instances like so:

```
// the ??? isn't relevant
Dictionary<System.Type, ???> mapping = new Dictionary<System.Type, ???>();

void Add<T>(Child<T> child) where T : CollectionBase
{
    mapping[typeof(T)] = ???;
}
```

This works fine.

But now imagine that you're given an object of apparent type `Parent`, but you know that its actual type is `Child<T>` (except that you don't know which `T`).

Is there any way to determine the `T` so that you're able to retrieve the corresponding mapping?

It is simple enough to workaround this by storing key information in other ways, but I'm mostly just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use reflection to get the actual type `T`, Is it what you want?

```
abstract class Parent { }

class Child<T> : Parent where T : CollectionBase { }

public class CollectionClass : CollectionBase { }
```

get generic type:

```
Parent p = new Child<CollectionClass>();

Type x = p.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault(); // the x will be tyepof(CollectionClass)
var isEqual = x == typeof(CollectionClass); // isEqual will be true
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of what you're asking:

```
void Main()
{
    Parent instance = new Child<string>();
    Type firstGenericTypeArgument = instance.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.First();
    Console.WriteLine(firstGenericTypeArgument == typeof(string));
}

abstract class Parent { }

class Child<T> : Parent { }
```

That produces `True`, so `firstGenericTypeArgument` is the same as `typeof(string)` in this example.